# I want to set interval between clicks with this code

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to set interval between clicks with this code. This is the script :

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
       inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you...tried anything? (Like using `setInterval`)?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you explain how this code is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set a bunch of time outs

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function () {
            inputs[i].click();      
        }, 1000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

or you can just use an interval

```
(function() {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name'),
        current = 0,
        timer = window.setInterval(
            function () {
                var input = inputs[current];
                if (input) {
                    input.click();
                    current++;
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        ,1000);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        // to get the actual value of i
    setInterval(function () {
        inputs[i].click();      
    }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: They want to pause between clicks, not keep clicking it.

Comment: @epascarello Exactly !